# Summing columns in a 2D array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a simple 2D array of integers named "round", with 5 elements on the horizontal and a variable number of "rows".

I want to calculate the total for each "column".  Here's my code:

```
var totals = [Int] ()

for column in 0...4 {
    for row in 0...round.count-1 {
        totals[column] = round[row][column] + totals[column]   }
}
```

I get a Playground "Fatal error: Index out of range"

In trying various options, it appears to be the "totals[column] = " assignment that throws the error, but I cannot determine why?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `totals[column]` since `totals` is an empty array it has no element at the index `column`.
It's similar to the following attempt:

```
var arr = [Int]()
arr[0] = 1 // <- fails, because there is no element at index 0
```

To fix this issue, you can initialize `totals` with zeros for the number of elements you want to store in the array:

```
var totals = Array(repeating: 0, count: round[0].count)
```

Or even simpler (but less dynamic):

```
var totals = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```